# Dataset and Charts tab missing in OMNeT++ 6.0 .anf file

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm a newbie on OMNeT++ trying to follow [part 7.5 of the tictoc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part7/#75-analyzing-the-results) on OMNeT++ 6.0. The simulation runs fine but I cannot post-process the results in `Tictoc18.anf` because it seems I don't have a `Dataset and Charts` tab:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I enable it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tictoc tutorial is slightly out of date. In OMNeT++ 6.0 there is no `Dataset` tab. Take a look at Chapter 9 of [OMNeT++ User Guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf).